# Error "The filter value is not valid for the field and filter type."

Tags: python, revit-api

When I use ScheduleFilterType with "HasValue" it works, but when I use ScheduleFilterType.Equal happens an error. should I use other method instead ScheduleFilter?

```
def CreateSchedule(category):

    TransactionManager.Instance.EnsureInTransaction(doc)
    schedule= ViewSchedule.CreateSchedule(doc, category)
    sd=schedule.Definition
    schedulablefields= sd.GetSchedulableFields()
    
    for field in schedulablefields:
        if(field.GetName(doc)=="Height Offset From Level"):
            sd.InsertField(field,0)
            fieldId=sd.GetFieldId(0)
            sd.InsertFilter( ScheduleFilter(fieldId, ScheduleFilterType.Equal, 10), 0) 

    TransactionManager.Instance.TransactionTaskDone()

categoriesSchedules=[ElementId(BuiltInCategory.OST_Floors)] 
for category in categoriesSchedules:
    CreateSchedule(category)
```

Comment: What error, please?

Comment: Have you searched the Revit API discussion forum? I found this for you: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/the-field-and-filter-type-cannot-be-used-to-filter-this/m-p/5083036

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.